# How to find largest possible covariance matrix, or largest set of columns with nonmissing pairwise covariance

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, statistics, dynamic-programming

I frequently have data where many observations are missing. And sometimes this means I have pairs of columns with no overlapping observations, so that I can't compute a covariance between the two.

But I'd like to know the largest set of columns for which all pairs of columns within the set have overlapping observations (at least 2, but you can assume if there is one there are many) so that I can compute a covariance matrix (all pairwise covariances) with no missing values.

As an example, consider the following python code.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> n = np.nan
>>> d = pd.DataFrame(
np.array(
[[1, n, 2, 4, 2, n, 6, n, 1, 1],
 [2, n, 3, 4, 4, n, 5, 4, 2, n],
 [1, 3, 4, 2, n, 2, 4, 2, n, 1],
 [1, 3, 4, 1, n, 1, 2, 1, n, 1]]),
        columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'])
>>> d
      a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    j
0  1.0  NaN  2.0  4.0  2.0  NaN  6.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  NaN  3.0  4.0  4.0  NaN  5.0  4.0  2.0  NaN
2  1.0  3.0  4.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  4.0  2.0  NaN  1.0
3  1.0  3.0  4.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  2.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
```

I'd like to make some function that can tell me which set of columns I should use to create the biggest covariance matrix. I think the answer in this case is `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j']`:

```
>>> d[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j']].cov() 
          a    b         c         d    f         g         h    j
a  0.250000  0.0 -0.083333  0.416667  0.0  0.250000  0.833333  0.0
b  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.0
c -0.083333  0.0  0.916667 -1.250000  0.0 -1.416667 -0.833333  0.0
d  0.416667  0.0 -1.250000  2.250000  0.5  2.416667  2.333333  0.0
f  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.500000  0.5  1.000000  0.500000  0.0
g  0.250000  0.0 -1.416667  2.416667  1.0  2.916667  2.166667  0.0
h  0.833333  0.0 -0.833333  2.333333  0.5  2.166667  2.333333  0.0
j  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.0
```

This is just a toy example. In practice, the datasets are large n=1000 or n=100000 or more. And the number of columns k=10 or k=200. I  think for large k this might be a really difficult problem. Seems like there might be a more efficient dynamic programming solution, as checking all different combinations of columns looks prohibitive.

Comment: If I have feature groups F, G, H and examples FG, FH, GH with the indicated feature groups present, can I take all three examples or not?

Comment: I think I don't understand your question, perhaps you could rephrase? If you're asking if in my specific example you could compute a covariance matrix with just columns 'f', 'g', and 'h', then, yes, you could.

Comment: To rephrase: if you drop the columns that weren't selected, does the resulting matrix have to be all non NaN entries or does it suffice that each pair of chosen columns has at least two defined features in common?

Comment: Just that each pair of columns needs to have at least two in common, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this question amounts to [finding a maximum clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Finding_maximum_cliques_in_arbitrary_graphs), which is a known hard problem. The standard algorithms for that problem will work better if you preprocess the comparability graph by merging sets of nodes with exactly the same observation pattern. Maybe there are other heuristics that could work for your graph.

To take a different tack, perhaps you could apply an SVD algorithm that handles missing data.